# How can we evaluate the predicted values in regression model

Tags: predictive-models, python, prediction

I am using regression model to predict values I have. How can evaluate the accuracy of prediction model (I'd like to see how the accuracy of predicted values).

I found different metrics, but it's only used with discrete data.

- Classification report
- Accuracy score
- Confusion matrix

Now, I can generate the summary using .summary() function. As an example [here](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/r-lm-summary.html) , it's nearly the same in R/Python;

I'd like to evaluate the performance, how good and accurate the predicted values that I got using GLM (with Binomial families ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pseudo R-squared measures, such as Nagelkerke, for an overview see:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. If I understand it very well. R-squared is always between 0 and 100%: - 0% indicates that the model is extremely bad.
- 100% indicates that the model explains all the variability of the response data around its mean ==> extremely good.

Comment: That seems right, except that a % interpretation is more difficult in the pseudo-R-squared case. It's okay in the linear case, where the ratio is explained against total variance.